# Android - Parse Single Item Response JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am under the gun on this one (about 6 hours to get this working) and I know I'm missing something completely simple here.

I am trying to parse a JSON response with a single piece of data, but my parse code isn't picking it up.

Here is the entire JSON response...

{"id":"4480"}

The "4480" is a potential alpha-numeric data response, so it could be something like "A427" as well.

Here is the code I am using to try to parse the single response. The problem is that userID is null - it's not picking up the 4480 in the JSON response. Could someone please point out where I'm messing this up?  Many thanks in advance for any help I can get!!

```
InputStream is = null;
                //http post
                try{
                    String postQuery = "my api post goes here";
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(postQuery);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                }

                //convert response to string
                try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }

                //parse json data
                try {
                JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject jsonid = userObject.getJSONObject("id");
                userID = jsonid.getString("id");
                }
```

Comment: What is messed up? Do you expect something that isn't happening? Do you get an exception? If so, post stack trace.

Comment: userID is null so my parse code isn't actually grabbing 4480

Comment: So if you try to log the result String, did it retrieve the data correctly?

Comment: Yep - i get the string just fine. it's somewhere in the //parse json data code that i'm not doing right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with JSON parsing, but based on [this](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/) example, I think you should change the `//parse json data` into this:

```
//parse json data
try {
    JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject(result);
    userID = userObject.getString("id");
} catch(Exception ex){
    //don't forget this
}
```

That is if the call to `new JSONObject(result)` is correct. Previously mentioned example shows something like this:

```
JSONObject userObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( result );
```

Comment: That did it!!  I knew it was something so simple but I just wasn't seeing what it was.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: NP, sometimes an unbiased look into things really helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
try{ 
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
    if (jsonObject.length() > 0) 
    {
     String userID  = jsonObject.optString("id");
     Log.e("TAG", "userID:"+ userID);
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Rmilligan2372 are you resolved your problem or not?